# Simple products are not showing on magento site: Magento

Tags: magento, notifications, product

I have recently created the new Product category and a simple product in it and shows it on front end using block but it giving this error "There are no products matching the selection." as the product is present there still it giving me error:

I have tried by clearing the cache and login and logout again but still the same issue.

Any Help in this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Did you set the correct website for the product? Also did you make sure you set the display in catalog for the product?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Check your product configuration:

- Product status must be "enabled"
- Visibility must be "catalog/search"
- Check product websites
- Does product connected to the desired category.

Also you can try to make reindex.

Hope this helps.

Comment: A re-index process is pending when i re-index this its generate an error. what to do with this

Comment: What kind of error you get? You can try run re-index via the command line https://www.branded3.com/blog/re-indexing-magento-command-line/

Comment: There was a problem with reindexing process.

Comment: I got this error:
Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= 'abs', ( - i.price), IF( = 'fixed', , ROUND(i.price * ( / 100), 4)))),

Comment: It's happened because somewhere you have not valid sql query. Try to find where it sql generated (try to search in the contents of files). Other solution - disable 3rd party extension, until the error disappears. I wish you success.

Comment: I am trying from 4 days but still no luck :(